# EF Code First (Azure) - An error occurred accessing the database

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Until recently my solution only had 1 web project. It is deployed to Azure.

There then became a requirement for WebJobs, which should share the data layer, so I extracted out any EntityFramework code (Configuration/IdentityModels) into their own project.

Now when I try to use the command line to "add-migration" I get the following error:

> An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the
>   connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is
>   correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used
>   to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure.

Here is what the App.Config file looks like for the EF project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True;Connect timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

It seems there is a required order of configuration child elements.

In my case I changed them to:

```
<configSections>...</configSections>
<startup>...</startup>
<system.data>...</system.data>
<connectionStrings>...</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>...</entityFramework>
```